# How to filter HTML table in which content is in div or span?

Tags: html, filter, html-table

I'm using an external wordpress plugin to print out a list of places (i.e. saloons) and I want to filter them by search text field.
The plugin outputs a table like in code below.

I have tried examples that used tr and td filtering but none worked, I have looked at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp and tried to edit the code to work with SPAN tags, but also and searched stackoverflow a lot.

**search field:**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search here">
```

**script:**

```
<script>
    // taken straight from w3schools
    function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                  txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                  if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                  }else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
             }
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

**table:**

```
<table id="exampletable" class="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="placeicon">
                <img src="icon.png">
            </td>
            <td class="placetext">
                <div class="placecontrols">
                    <a href="examplemap.html"><img src="icon2.png"></a>
                </div>
                <span class="text">
                    <strong>Example Place</strong>
                    <br>Address 123
                    <br>Phone: 123456789
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
```

I expect a search field to filter the table where the names are in SPAN tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me quite some time to figure this out.

First, the id of your table and js are not same, please change that to `exampletable`.

secondly coming to the code. instead of doing `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`
try `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("strong")[0];`

Or use this

```
 <script>
    // taken straight from w3schools
    function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("exampletable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td= tr[i].getElementsByTagName("strong")[0];
            if (td) {
                  txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                  if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                  }else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
             }
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.  You had a few things wrong with your code:
* The ID to select your table was incorrect
* Inside the loop you had it looking for the very first `<td>` element with             `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]`, yet the actual text you wanted to search was in a different element.

I also cleaned up some variables, and now it's using `querySelector` and querySelectorAll` which allows you to use CSS style selectors, with are a bit easier to deal with!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var txtValue = "";
  var filter = document.querySelector("#myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
  var tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var thisRow = tr[i];
    var textElement = thisRow.querySelector(".text");
    if (textElement) {
      txtValue = textElement.textContent || textElement.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        thisRow.style.display = "";
      } else {
        thisRow.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search here">

<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="placeicon">
        <img src="icon.png">
      </td>
      <td class="placetext">
        <div class="placecontrols">
          <a href="examplemap.html"><img src="icon2.png"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="text">
            <strong>Example Place</strong>
            <br>Address 123
            <br>Phone: 123456789
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="placeicon">
        <img src="icon.png">
      </td>
      <td class="placetext">
        <div class="placecontrols">
          <a href="examplemap.html"><img src="icon2.png"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="text">
            <strong>Another Place</strong>
            <br>Address 456
            <br>Phone: 987654321
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="placeicon">
        <img src="icon.png">
      </td>
      <td class="placetext">
        <div class="placecontrols">
          <a href="examplemap.html"><img src="icon2.png"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="text">
            <strong>Completely Different Place</strong>
            <br>Address 472
            <br>Phone: 1684233445
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```